# 20.04 lubuntu installation failure to resize partition

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, lubuntu, 20.10

**Goal:** dual boot Windows / 20.0X lubuntu: Windows-10 is already installed& working.

**Question:** What diagnostics / corrective steps can be performed to overcome:

[image]

Comment: If trying resize a Windows partition, do it from Windows, not Linux.  Is Windows fast boot off?  Is Windows using basic or dynamic partitions?

Comment: @crip659 Please consider posting an answer with suggested diagnostics procedures and any references that you think might be helpful?  Thank you

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to give a proper answer.  Do know that while we can work Windows partitions from Linux, it should be last resort.  Windows does it better.  Linux also has a lot of trouble just seeing Windows dynamic partitions, which Windows seem to be using more of, and it is a very bad idea to try to work on Windows partitions if fast boot(hibernation) is on.  These are just basics, imagine the better ones on here can give quite a few commands to see what happen.